# rename randomly files on a USB device

Tags: shell-script, rename

I would like to rename all of my files of my USB device randomly. Indeed, in my car, my tuner has not the random function.

I think I can do it with PHP ... but I'm pretty sure it is possible to do something shorter in shell script, right?

An idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are running Linux, that you want to randomly order all files in the current directory and that no file name contains a newline:

```
printf '%s\n' * | shuf | nl -n rz -s - |
while IFS= read -r name; do
  mv -- "${name#*-}" "$name"
done
```

The `printf` command prints the file names, one per line. [`shuf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/shuf-invocation.html) applies a random permutation to the input lines. `nl` adds prefixes like `000001-`, `000002-`, etc. to each line. The `while` loop iterates over all the lines. The `mv` command renames `foo.mp3` to `000001-foo.mp3`, etc.

Comment: Oh thank you for your help. I try that tonight ! It seems to be the best way without any risk of collision

Answer (score 3):

You can add a random number of equal width as prefix, that's what I'm doing to randomize my audio files:

```
for i in *; do mv "$i" "$(seq -w 0 999 | shuf -n 1)_$i"; done
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work: this is a convoluted way of generating a random number for each input, and there is a risk of collision.

Comment: Yes there is a risk of collision, but this doesn't matter for his use case. Only the random prefix might occur more than once, not the whole file name.

Comment: It's probably not that important given the use case, but the resulting output is slightly biased towards lexicographic order of file names. E.g. given files `a.mp3`, `b.mp3` and `c.mp3`, the order a,b,c is slightly more likely than a,c,b or b,a,c or b,c,a or c,a,b which are slightly more likely than c,b,a.

Comment: Thank you for your snippet. Even if the collision is not important, the method of Gilles seems cleaner. But thank you for your intervention